# consider defining a bean of type 'Mapper' in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot

I'm making SpringBoot Project and following some instructions for testing Spring Boot.

While I tried to connect mysql DB with project, service cannot find the mapper.

i don't know why it cannot find the mapper...

```
@Service
public class TestService {
    
    @Autowired
    TestMapper mapper;
    
    public List<TestVo> selectTest(){
        return mapper.selectTest();
    }
}
```

this is the service code and

```
@Repository
@Mapper
public interface TestMapper {
    List<TestVo> selectTest();
}
```

this is the mapper code

the following error is

```
Field mapper in com.steve.firstBoot.test.service.TestService required a bean of type 'com.steve.firstBoot.test.mapper.TestMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.steve.firstBoot.test.mapper.TestMapper' in your configuration.
```

I will post the image of my packages setting...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a class that implements your interface and annotate it with one of the bean stereotype annotations, i.e @Component, @Service, @Repository
2. Remove the @Repository annotation from your interface

Answer (score 1):

Spring can not create an object for the interface. Make sure there should be an implementation class of every interface that needs to be autowired.

After this people generally follow 2 approaches.

1.Mark the interface with @Repository/@Service based on functionality and all its implementation class with @Component

2.Can directly mark implementation class with @Repository/@Service without even marking interface.

Any of them is fine.